# I have written a poem and I am asking if the poem has any errors in the grammar

Tags: grammaticality

Nie werde ich ohne dich leben, 
denn ist da keinen Grund dazu. 
Doch in letzter Zeit ich mehr geweint statt mit dir lebe genießen.

Sie sagten mir und sie warnten mich, 
«dein Leben auf Träume bauen nicht». 
Anderseits war ich jung und es schien der bessere Weg.

Aber es bist du, dass ich für existiert hat. 
Es bist du, für den ich gegeben hatte. 
Und wo immer ich ging und was immer ich tat, 
es bist du.

So lebte ich weiter und gab meine Seele für dich in der hoffen, 
dass eines Tages meiner Träume wahr würde. 
Leider jetzt sei ich verwickelt inmitten Wirklichkeit, 
meine Träume werden grau in der Dunkelheit, 
bitte hilf mir zu realisieren, 
es bist du, für den ich lebe, 
es bist du, für den ich gebe. 
Und wo immer ich gehe und was immer ich tue, es bist du.

Answer (score 1):

There are some small errors in a couple of sentences. Here is a more correct version (although you might need to adjust some phrases in order to regain the rhythm)

```
Nie werde ich ohne dich leben, denn es gibt keinen Grund dazu. 
Doch in letzter Zeit hab' ich mehr geweint, statt mit dir das Leben genossen.

Sie sagten mir und sie warnten mich, «dein Leben auf Träume baue nicht». 
Doch war ich jung und es schien der bessere Weg.

Aber es bist du, für den ich existierte.
Es bist du, für den ich gab. Und wo immer ich ging und was immer ich tat, es bist du.

So lebte ich weiter und gab meine Seele für dich in der Hoffnung, dass eines Tages meine Träume wahr würden. 
Leider jetzt bin ich verwickelt inmitten der Wirklichkeit, meine Träume werden grau in der Dunkelheit, bitte hilf mir zu realisieren, es bist du, für den ich lebe, es bist du, für den ich gebe. 
Und wo immer ich gehe und was immer ich tue, es bist du.
```

Some remarks:

- "Doch in letzter Zeit hab' ich mehr geweint, statt mit dir das Leben genossen."
  You could also say "Doch in letzter Zeit ich mehr geweint, statt mit dir das Leben zu genießen", which is gramatically not that perfect, but fits better into a poem.
- "[...] und gab meine Seele für dich in der Hoffnung [...]"
  This would mean that you gave your soul away, or abandoned your soul in favor of the other one. If you'd like to express that you gave your soul to the other one, use "und gab dir meine Seele".
  Also in this sentence, you used "in der hoffen", you could either say "in der Hoffnung" or "hoffend" (hoping).
- Also, be aware that some sentences wouldn't be said like this in the real world, but only work in a poem: "Leider jetzt bin ich verwickelt inmitten der Wirklichkeit", you would normally say "Jetzt bin ich leider in der Wirklichkeit verwickelt", but that does not sound that lyrical. Another alternative would be "Doch bin ich nun verwickelt in der Wirklichkeit, und meine Träume werden grau [...]"

I hope that helps!

Comment: It sure does - thank you so very much and all the best to you!! I hope and pray God blesses you in some way for that!! Once again, thanks!!

Comment: Depending on who you address, "für **den** ich existierte/gab" might be "für **die** ..."

Comment: Thank you Bodo. The poem is about me addressing God and acknowledging that I was possibly too much of a dreamer in my younger years, but at the same time, I was trying my best for Him nevertheless.  So would your suggestion fit with that?  Convaldo, in hindsight I would have said the same when I first posted the question, if I had thought of it - but anyway, does that still fit in with your suggestions as well. Thank you to both of you and I look forwards to hearing from both of you again, if you would be so kind as to help me one more time.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: As God usually is addressed as "Him", "für den ich existierte" is correct. It's the male version, as well as the general one, when you don't address someone in particular (in the sense of "Du bist der Mensch für den ich existiere"). If you address a female person, you would use "für die". And feel free to keep asking, but be aware that stackexchange generally doesn't accept review-requests, but more general ones that concern more general aspects that others could find useful as well.

Comment: Thank you Convaldo - all the best.

Comment: I wanted to add more to that last comment but the editor timed out on me, so here is the addition: They (German Stack Exchange) wrote to me and asked to state a reason why a dictionary or similar did not help.  The answer to that is, that I ran my Poem through several online grammar checkers and all of them were stating that the way I had written the Poem originally was correct.  I had heard however that the accuracy of online grammar checkers left something to be desired, so I posted it here to try and find some peace of mind about it.  Anyhow, once again - thank you.